# Transactions in Spring/hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

we are using Spring and hibernate in our project and i have noticed that we have defined   `<tx:annotation-driven />` in sprint context file and if i put `@Transactional`annotation for method i am successfully able to interact with database but if i remove `@Transactional` annotation from method i am getting exception stating that `"No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here"`

is there any way by which i can define all the select operation as non Transactional(i mean without `@Transactional` annotation)  and update and insert as Transactional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by using below code in context xml file.

```
  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
      <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
      <tx:attributes>
         <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
         <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/> 
         <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
         <tx:method name="*"/>       
      </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>

      <aop:config>
          <aop:pointcut id="allServiceMethods" expression="execution(* com.test.*.*(..))"/>
          <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allServiceMethods"/>
    </aop:config>
```

As by default `read-only="false"` for `@Transactional` annotation.
So we need to make it as `read-only="true"` for all read operation(Thanks Affe for pointer)

to set `read-only="true"` for all select select operation make sure that you start your method name from `get` and rest below code will code for us. you can change your below configuration as per your need.

```
 <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
```

For more information you can refer to below link

[Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)

Answer (score 1):

Using `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` is usually the best thing for select-only operations.  Using hibernate in auto-commit mode can be wasteful when multiple select statements are needed to complete an operation.

Comment: Thanks for reply...is there any way by which i can execute my all select queries without @Transactional annotation even though i ahve <tx:annotation-driven /> in context xml